# How to control the space between paragraph elements?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code here:

```
<div class="paper">
        <h1>Welcome back, <?php echo $_SESSION["username"] ?>!</h1>
        <p>This is your space, here are your stats:</p>
    <p>Username: <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?> </p>
    <p>Coins: <?php echo "$" . $_SESSION['coins']; ?> </p>
    <?php if($admin){ echo "<p>Note: This account has admin access.</p>
    <form action='admincontrol.php'>
      <input type='submit' value='Admin Panel'/>
    </form><br>"; } ?>
    <form action="success.php" method="post" enctype="multi-part/form-data">
      <input name="Logout" type="submit" value="logout">
    </form>
    </div>
```

And it displays like this:
[image]

How could I use my CSS to control the space within username and coins? It looks really awkward skipping and entire line to show coins.

So instead of:

```
Username: xflare
//Empty space
Coins: 100
```

It should be:

```
Username: xflare
Coins: 100
```

How could I do this using CSS?

Comment: Set the margin/padding on the paragraphs accordingly. Or use a `<br />` instead of two paragraphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use one paragraph and use a `<br>` to get to the next line, or you could set the margin of the paragraph tags to 0px.